# Two Report Server pointing to Single Report Server DB instance

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I want to install two Reporting Service instance on two different servers which will point to a single Report Server Database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly point two different instances to a single database, you can use the Reporting Services configuration tool to set that up (use the database tab). I've never done it myself though so i don't know how nice they will play together, especially if you intend to encrypt the database.

Why would you want to do that though, is it for administrative reasons? It's easy enough to deploy the same reports to two different servers, and both sets of reports can look at the same database to get their data.

**Edit:**

> Client standard process is to have application and DB on different Server thats why We need SSRS on T1 Server and its Report Server DB in T2

Absolutely this is possible - you can have the database in any SQLServer instance that is visible to the server hosting the web component of SSRS. Just use the tool i mentioned above.

Comment: Now in let say T1 Server we have SSRS and Report Server Databases. Client standard process is to have application and DB on different Server thats why We need SSRS on T1 Server and its Report Server DB in T2. So basically T1 will point to T2 Database

Comment: Now we have Reporting Service and its DB on Same Server(T1). We want Reporting Service to be on another machine(T2) and point to T1 Report Server DB. We want both should work I can see the reports from T1 and T2 also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

At work we have several vm-servers each with an instance of ssrs-2005 on it (something like 20 of them) and then a single vm-server holding all databases. It works OK with a few problems:

1. It is hard to manage the securities such that users of different instances have different levels of access
2. We renamed the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases for one of the instances so that they had a separate set of reports and this has caused no end of hassle. MS do not support renaming of theses are they are hard-coded throughout!

In your case I don't see why you should have a problem but not entirely sure I see why you would do it! Make sure to backup the access key for the DB before you start.

Reporting services Configuration Manager --> Encryption Keys --> Backup