# Multiple SQL Server Reporting Services machines using same database instance

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to have multiple SSRS instances (different versions) setup on separate machines both configured to point at the same database instance?

I want to have a Reporting Services 2008 on one machine (legacy application), reporting services 2014 (new application), but both of them pointing to the same SQL Server 2008 database instance on the database server.

The SSRS 2008 is already configured and working - I want to add the SSRS 2014. What kind of special configuration do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: It is certainly possible. Check the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908214/two-report-server-pointing-to-single-report-server-db-instance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Reporting Services Configuration Manager to change the location of the database that Reporting Service points to:

[image]

This is directly from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx).